# Assets pipeline rails 3 structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

I have the following structure in my assets folder of the app :

```
- app
  - assets
    - application.scss
    - themes
      - mytheme
        - default.scss
```

And in my application.haml.html I do :

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
= stylesheet_link_tag "themes/mytheme/default"
```

Now when I precompile my assets, the application.css is in my public/assets folder but the default.css of mytheme is not there. This gives me always an error in staging environment :

> ActionView::Template::Error (themes/mytheme/default.css isn't
>   precompiled)

What do I have to do so that the compiler is taking all my assets to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your config file to something like this:

config.assets.precompile += ['default.css']

And then running the rake task to precompile. You may need to include the full path to the asset. You can find specific information about the [asset pipeline here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and [information about compiling assets here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew that he was just checking the application.js and the application.css

Answer (score 1):

You also could have a different layout for each theme. Although it is not very DRY, sometimes is good to duplicate some code in order to decouple app modules reducing impact of negative changes. Something analog to the [Fragile base class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) problem.

I'd take advantage of the [`index` manifest](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) and organize your `app/assets` into decoupled modules. The following structure belongs to a project I'm currently working on. 
Let's say you app is composed out of three modules: the public side, an admin UI and, e.g., a CRM to let your agents track the selling process at your company:

```
app/assets/
├── coffeescripts
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── components
│   │   ├── index.coffee
│   │   └── initializers
│   ├── application
│   │   ├── components
│   │   ├── index.sass
│   │   └── initializers
│   └── crm
│       ├── components
│       ├── index.sass
│       └── initializers
├── images
│   ├── admin
│   ├── application
│   └── crm
└── stylesheets
    ├── admin
    │   ├── components
    │   └── index.sass
    ├── application
    │   ├── components
    │   └── index.sass
    └── crm
        ├── components
        └── index.sass

21 directories, 6 files
```

You could have one module per theme, and probably `core_theme` containing the common stylesheets, images and eventually JS components.

Either you go for a single share layout or not, you could then just adding the following lines will lead you to a more organised codebase and properly precompiled production assets.

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'theme_a'
= javascript_include_tag 'theme_a'
```

Don't forget to update your `application.rb` so they will be precompiled properly:

```
  config.assets.precompile = %w(admin.js application.js crm.js 
                                admin.css application.css crm.css)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to avoid exception:
First is:
Do not use `= stylesheet_link_tag "themes/mytheme/default"` in the layout or views. Just add proper instructions in `application.css` file (I mean `require` statements).
Second: 
 you can turn on 'live asset compilation' in `application.rb` file.

And third:
 you can add "themes/mytheme/default" to compile path for sprockets.
Here is additional resources to read: [Asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)